# Sort by one variable, group by another, and select first row in SQL Query in R

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

I need to apply a procedure in SQL that is easy for me since R, but has been really tortuous in SQL.

I need to sort the data from highest to lowest by two variables, group based on another variable, and select the first item in each group.

I leave the code that I am trying to pass from R to SQL. Unfortunately the dbplyr package throws me an error when trying to convert one language to another: Error: `first()` is only available in a windowed (`mutate()`) context

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dbplyr)
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
copy_to(con, mtcars)

mtcars2 <- tbl(con, "mtcars")
mtcars2

mtcars2 %>% 
  arrange(-mpg,-disp) %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(hp = first(hp)) %>% 
  show_query()
```

It seems to me that the DISTINCT ON function could help me.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(dbplyr)

con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
copy_to(con, mtcars)

mtcars2 <- tbl(con, "mtcars")

mtcars2 %>%
  arrange(-mpg,-disp) %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(hp = first(hp)) %>% 
  select(cyl, hp) %>% 
  distinct %>% 
  show_query

#> <SQL>
#> SELECT DISTINCT `cyl`, FIRST_VALUE(`hp`) OVER (PARTITION BY `cyl` ORDER BY -`mpg`, -`disp`) AS `hp`
#> FROM `mtcars`
#> ORDER BY -`mpg`, -`disp`
```

See: https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/issues/129

Comment: Thank you very much, I am testing the code (the original table is very large). I followed your code but removing the distinct() function that seemed unnecessary to me after having grouped by cyl

Comment: I guess you really need `distinct`, @NicolasRatto! `mutate` does not summarize and, consequently, one gets many repeated rows! I confirmed that by running the code on `mtcars`.

Comment: You're right, I don't know why I thought the mutate was a summarize. I'll go back to testing distinct.

Comment: When I test it with my real data I get the following error:

When SELECT DISTINCT is specified, the items in ORDER BY must appear in the select list

Comment: @NicolasRatto: Do you really want the `first` of `hp` or the minimum of `hp`? With `min`, there is no need to `arrange` (that corresponds to `SQL ORDER BY`...

Comment: I really need the first...

Comment: It worked for me by removing the last line of ORDER BY code. Thank you very much for your help.